# yogakit/yogakit.modulemap' not found React Native, on Apple M1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, apple-m1

I am trying to compile a hello-world react-native app that has `WatermelonDB` configured. I have a M1 Macbook Pro M1 and am following the instructions given [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/offline-app-react-native-watermelondb/) and [and here](https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Installation.html#ios-react-native) to set up the project for `Watermelon`. Once setup, the compile for `Android` works correctly, but the compile for iOS fails with the following error:

[image]

This issue is discussed [over here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29605), but the problem is that this error can occur in a **lot** of different situations. As a result there are loads of different suggestions, not all of which are particular to this issue arising on an M1.

I am using Xcode 13.4 and am trying to get the application launching on an iOS simulator as I do not have an iOS phone to test on.

Please do not offer solutions that involve installing older versions of `react-native` or `Xcode`. I am looking the solution to get the latest version of `react-native` working on the latest version of `Xcode`.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted please care to elaborate why they downvoted. This is a very specific question about a specific problem that affects a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working by making use of `Rosetta`. I did the following steps before I start creating the project.

1. Find `Xcode` in applications folder, right click on it and select "Get Info"

[image].

2. In the info dialog that opens up, check the checkbox labeled "Open using Rosetta" and then close the dialog.

[image]

After doing this, I followed all of the steps in the tutorial that I linked to in the question.  The log still showed the error that I originally posted:

[image]

But the build continued, completed and was successfully launched on the `iOS` simulator.

[image]

Maybe there are better solutions that don't depend on `Rosetta`. But this works for me for now.

Edit:
Another thing that I did differently the second time I did this tutorial was to start the `Xcode` setup by double clicking on the `.xcworkspace` rather than on the `.xcodeproj` file. Not sure if this was part of the solution.